# Installing packages from pip3 always failed because of unknown version

Tags: linux, python, raspbian, pip

`Linux raspberrypi 4.9.78-v7+ #1084 SMP Thu Jan 25 18:05:49 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux`

I am on Raspbian Jessie and I had to install `python 3.6.4` from source (apparently that is the only way).

Then as the usual routine, I carried on with `pip3` installation and it was a success. Then I tried to install the packages that I need, such as `numpy`, `pillow`, `matplotlib` and so on and this is the result I'm getting.

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pillow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pillow`

Is there anything I am missing?

`which python -> /usr/bin/python`

`pip -V -> pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`

`which python3 -> /usr/local/bin/python3`

`pip3 -V -> pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)`

Answer (score 1):

This is something related on how PyPi is managing the access via HTTPS over HTTP connections.

Use --trusted-host:  pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org NAMEOFTHEPACKAGE

if you're using python3.*

pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org NAMEOFTHEPACKAGE

[Check out a similar issue and explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi/39124754#39124754)